# Github Pages Website CSS not applying to HTML page

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages, web-hosting

I have been trying for awhile now to host my Portfoliocv on github and have never had any luck with getting my CSS to apply on the URL.
-This is how it is linked in the html document
 `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">`
The styles.css is not in a folder and works locally but just doesn't work in pages.

Previously had the following
 `<link rel="stylesheet"  href="styles.css">`

But switched it to this to see if this would fix it
 `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">`

Comment: Here is the link to the website as well sorry I forgot to include that. https://goldenkunai.github.io/Portfoliocv/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The previous change I had mentioned apparently worked, it just took awhile to show the changes.